# post the screenshot of a viewcontroller as url on facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to post the screenshot of a viewcontroller as url on facebook.How this can be done.I know how to post text but how can I take screenshot of a viewcontroller programatically and post it as url on facebook?Please help with some code in objective c.

Comment: You need to apply `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` to take Image of your VC, then image to upload on server, Finally with Server image URL, post it to FB.

Comment: Kindly do explain with code ...

Comment: first let me know do you have server to upload image?

Comment: yes...but I actually need your help with taking screenshot of the viewcontroller only...,If u ll help me with that,rest  I can manage

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Comment: yes..the issue is resolved now

Comment: Cool @TestShroff Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Objective C** you can do to take image.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size,false, 0.0);
[self.ImageBgView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage * image  = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

hope this help